# Калькулятор Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь написать калькулятор для расчета стоимости ремонта пола

```js
$("#summ span").text("0");

        var totalSum = 0;
        var inputFloor = parseInt($("#inputFloor").val()) * parseInt($("input[name='floor']").attr("value"));
        $('.floor').on("change",function(){
            if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) {
                $(".input_size").css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
        $("#inputFloor").on("change",function() {
            if ($(this).val() > 0) {
                $("#inputFloor").each(function() {
                    totalSum += inputFloor;
                });
            }
        });

        $("#summ span").text(totalSum);
```

```css
.input_size {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="floor">
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Плитка</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Ламинат</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Паркетная доска</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Линолеум</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Ковролин</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Половая доска</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Пробковое покрытие</p>
  <p><input class="floor" type="radio" name="floor" value="1500">Теплый пол</p>
  <div class="input_size">
    <p><strong>Площадь пола:</strong></p>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input id="inputFloor" name="300" size="2" type="text" value="0"> кв.м.</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calc_footer">
  <p id="summ">Итого: <strong><span></span></strong> р.</p>
</div>
```

Но не считает ни в какую. Что упустил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parseInt($("input[name='floor']").attr("value")
```

Это бросилось в глаза, как минимум. У вас же много таких элементов - оно не будет считать от значения выбранного элемента. Можно заменить на `parseInt( $('.floor:checked').val() )`

Второе, саму объявленную переменную `var inputFloor` надо бы перенести под функцию `$("#inputFloor").on("change"...` чтобы прямо после смены - обновить его значение. А до этого момента - у вас же `$("#inputFloor")` пустой...

```
var totalSum = 0;
...
$("#inputFloor").each(function() {
  totalSum += inputFloor;
});
```

К этим кускам тоже есть вопросы... 
У вас же всего один выбранный пол будет, а не несколько. Поэтому можно было это всё убрать, оставив лишь `$("#summ span").text(inputFloor);` под функцией `on('change` ... А по-хорошему, заменить on('change') на `on('input'...)` — тогда ответ будет появляться сразу при вводе

Comment: Благодарю. Может есть какой-нибудь хороший пример для такой задачи? Разобраться. Это так сказать на коленке быстро набросал, ибо уже нужно запускать проект + калькулятор этот нужно будет еще обкатывать

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#summ span").text("0");

var totalSum = 0;

$('.floor').on("change",function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) {
        $(".input_size").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
$("#inputFloor").on("change",function() {
    var inputFloor = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("input[name='floor']:checked").val());
    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        $("#inputFloor").each(function() {
            totalSum += inputFloor;
        });
    }
    $("#summ").find('span').text(totalSum);
});
```

Comment: Есть и без того сомнительные моменты в вашем коде, не исправлял - просто "поправил" чтоб работал код. Надеюсь, это задел на будущее у вас.

Comment: Благодарю. Идея такова, что будет три раздела калькулятора:
- Пол
- Потолок
- Стены

Соответственно при выборе нужного пункта, выводится поле для ввода площади поверхности. И рассчитывается исходя их формулы "цена за м2 * площадь м2"

Это заготовка калькулятора, в принципе самое простое решение.

Еще такой момент: подразумевается, что пользователь может выбрать только потолок и стены, итоговая сумма считается из заполненных полей

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/iwneid/pen/Lvegqy?editors=1010

```
var totalSum = 0;

function total() {
  var checkedElement = parseInt($('input[name="floor"]:checked').val()),
      inputSum = parseInt($("#inputFloor").val());
  if(!inputSum) {
    $("#inputFloor").val('1');
  }
  $('#summ span').html(checkedElement * inputSum);
};

$('.floor').on("change", function(){
  if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) {
    $(".input_size").css('display', 'block');
  }
  total();
});

$("#inputFloor").on("change",function() {
  if ($(this).val() > 0) {
    $("#inputFloor").each(function() {
      totalSum += inputFloor;
    });
    total();
  }
});

$("#summ span").text(totalSum);
```